# How can I edit a array in the mutation and refresh it?

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

I am trying to edit an element in my array, first, calling an action doing a put to my backend and second, commit a mutation, with the element altered.

However, My array does not update automatically and I need to something to refresh my table that contains my array elements.

Another question is it ok doing this kind of thing. I mean, if another person is logged in other section will see the old value till refreshing his/her page. is it right?

MY action

```
async editPersonnel({
    commit
  }, data) {
    console.log(data);
    let id = data.personnelID;
    let personnel = await this.$axios.$put(
      `http://localhost:56980/api/Personnel/DealerEmployee/${id}`,
      data
    );
    commit("EDIT_DEALER_PERSONNEL", personnel);
  },
```

My mutation

```
  EDIT_DEALER_PERSONNEL(state, EDITemployee) {
    debugger
    const postIndex = state.dealerPersonnel.findIndex(
      post => post.personnelID === EDITemployee.personnelID
    );

    state.dealerPersonnel[postIndex] = EDITemployee;
  },
```

Comment: I think your 'personnel' variable will be more complex than you expect as it is the whole response from your axios call so your mutation probably doesn't work because personnel.personnelID isn't a thing. Try `Console.log(personnel)` in your action to see what you get. You'll probably have to send personnel.data or something to your mutation.

Comment: The mutation works, the array is updated, however, in it doesn't show in the screen, only after I clicked or do something

Comment: How are you accessing the array to display on your screen?

Comment: I am accessing through state.dealerPersonnel in a computed method. ```computed: {
    formTitle() {
      return this.editedIndex === -1 ? "New Item" : "Edit Item";
    },

    personnelDealer() {
      return this.$store.state.personnel.dealerPersonnel;
    },```